# Restconf not getting switchport vlan information

Tags: vlan, ios-xe, api

I have a couple of catalyst switches which I'm experiencing an interesting issue using APIs not pulling all the information I need.

The switches are running IOS-XE 17.6.3, but I have also seen the same issue on v16.6 code and 17.6.4

If you have a trunk interface with enough VLAN allowed entries that the cli displays the list as multiple lines with the “add” option e.g.:

```
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1

switchport trunk native vlan 99

switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-4,8,10,30,40,50,51,53,61,65,72,85

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 202,241,342,400,1101

switchport mode trunk

switchport nonegotiate

end
```

When I use RESTCONF to interrogate the config with a URL like:https://IPADDR/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/interface/TenGigabitEthernet

The results only list the final 'add' line - and lose the 'switchport trunk allowed vlan' line:

```
 //

"switchport": {

  "Cisco-IOS-XE-switch:mode": {

    "trunk": {}

  },

  "Cisco-IOS-XE-switch:nonegotiate": [null],

  "Cisco-IOS-XE-switch:trunk": {

    "allowed": {

      "vlan": {

        "add": "202,241,342,400,1101"

      }

    },

    "native": {

      "vlan": {

        "vlan-id": 99

      }

    }

  }

}
```

It appears it doesn't see the information regarding the config line:

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-4,8,10,30,40,50,51,53,61,65,72,85
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to get this information or is this a bug?

Comment: Certainly sounds like a bug. Have you look through the CCO bug tool? (or version release notes)

Comment: I couldn't find anything using the bug tool but I'll have a look. The fact that I get  "add": "202,241,342,400,1101" in the response suggests my syntax is correct but I just wanted to double check in case anyone else came across this.

Just found this https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCwd97166